# I have a jsPDF error

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I am trying to generate a pdf of a page that I have rendered in the browser. I have a button which you can click but it generates an error. Can anyone help me out please

Lots of jsPDF questions (some with answers) but not this one, any ideas. Not doing anything clever. Just a straight copy/paste from the examples.

My html

```
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>

<div class="row" id="dashb">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>World</p>
    </div>

</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/vis/css/vis.css" />
<link href="~/Content/css/leaflet120.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/css/leaflet07.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/leaflet120.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/js/leaflet07.js"></script>

<script src="/Content/vis/js/wrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vis/js/d3tip.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vis/js/d3pie.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vis/js/vis.columnChart.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vis/js/vis.lineChart.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vis/js/vis.pieChart.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vis/js/vis.circleMap.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/vis/js/vis.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/html2canvas.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(function () {

        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        $('#cmd').click(function () {
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.fromHTML(
                $('#dashb').html(), 15, 15,
                { 'width': 170, 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers },
                function () { doc.save('sample-file.pdf'); }
            );

        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: element.className.split is not a function
    at elementHandledElsewhere (jspdf.debug.js:7215)
    at DrillForContent (jspdf.debug.js:7426)
    at DrillForContent (jspdf.debug.js:7427)
    at DrillForContent (jspdf.debug.js:7427)
    at DrillForContent (jspdf.debug.js:7427)
    at jspdf.debug.js:7595
    at done (jspdf.debug.js:7470)
    at Image.img.onerror.img.onload (jspdf.debug.js:7492)
```

This is my code

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        $('#cmd').click(function () {
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.fromHTML(
                $('#dashb').html(), 15, 15,
                { 'width': 170, 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers },
                function () { doc.save('sample-file.pdf'); }
            );

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your `click()` event handler up to the beginning of the function. I included this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfb7p6oe/1/) showing it working.

```
$('#cmd').click(function () {
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML(
        $('#dashb').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },
        function () {
            doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
        }
    );
});
```